# Diffence between using url or not in django url config

Tags: django

What would be the difference between using url of 'nothing' in the django urls config?

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Or

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#url):

> You can use the url() function, instead of a tuple, as an argument to
>   patterns(). This is convenient if you want to specify a name without
>   the optional extra arguments dictionary.

In your case, the behaviour is the same.